# Splitting a csv bulk import to postgres into smaller blocks using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, python, copy

I have a number of csv-files that I would like to import into my postgres-database. Since each file is quite large (200m-2bn records/file) I believe it would be better to add each file in smaller batches.

FOr comparison, when using MS-SQL and using bcp, files get automatically split into 1000 record batches. That is exactly what I (think I) want to do with COPY.

My main script is Python 3.5.2, the database is PostgreSQL 9.5.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am using psycopg2's copy functionality (on the simple account of it being the first that worked). I'm happy to change that, as long as I can call it from python (since I need to do some other processing per file -- organizing files, searching, determining the target stage table, unzip, cleanup, etc. -- since I am not sure how exactly the data transfer works using this method. Per psycopg2's doc the sql-version of copy is used (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), not the command line version. However I suspect the entire file will be buffered through stdin, but again, I'm not sure.

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database=dbname, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
cur = con.cursor()
f = open(pathTempFile)
cur.copy_expert("""copy public.stage_datafile from STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER""",
    file=f)
f.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

This process works fine, and I'm not even sure there are any drawbacks. However, it seems there might be a better/more robust way? I will use a trigger to export the data from the staging tables into the normalized main tables, surely that would benefit from smaller data blocks?

I appreciate any suggestions on making this process more robust.

---

Addendum:

- I only need to import the data once, not regularly.
- I could also use `sed` to generate some temporary files and import those, in fact I'm doing that while debugging

Comment: An alternative to `sed` is use the linux `split` command to break your csv's into smaller chunks. Eg. `split -l10000 yourfile.csv pg_`, where `pg_` is the prefix for the resulting files, though you might want to use input filename ("yourfile" in this example) as the prefix, so no csv's get overwritten by running `split` on subsequent files. `-l10000` splits on 10k lines. If you need more advanced ETL options (outside of Python), there's also a slick tool called [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/howto/csv.html).

Comment: In addition to what Evan Carroll said, you can create your staging table [UNLOGGED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) to save on WAL generation.

Comment: Thanks @bma for the suggestion! I'll try ´sed` once I run into problems, but i've made the tables unlogged. A colleague suggested to check out autogrowth options and datatable types, but I haven't had the time to try those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a number of csv-files that I would like to import into my postgres-database. Since each file is quite large (200m-2bn records/file) I believe it would be better to add each file in smaller batches.

Probably not. It'll work just fine. You're probably better off running the `CREATE TABLE` and `COPY` in the same transaction though, that way you generate minimal WAL.

Comment: Thanks! I don't drop the entire table, I just remove all records. So I only have to create it once, so I don't think I'll have to save at that point.

Comment: @phi use `TRUNCATE` and `COPY` in the same transaction, it'll be faster.